# Is there any difference between strncat and strncpy to write safe string copy function?

Tags: c, string, c89

I have come across two popular ways to write a safe copy function that is portable and conforms to C89.

Example 1:

```
strncpy(dst, src, size);
dst[size - 1] = '\0';
```

Example 2:

```
dst[0] = '\0'
strncat(dst, src, size - 1);
```

Do these approaches provide the exact same result, or would there be any differences in `dst` contents between one example and the other?

Comment: You could also try snprintf, which will give you a slightly more useful return value, i.e. the total number of character written.

Comment: @Griddoor good point. So a potential problem is in fact that neither works properly if `size == 0`; and `size` has a different meaning in each of the examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are technically different. Though you may not care about the trivial difference.

e.g. if you initialize like this:

```
char dst[] = "abcdefg";
char src[] = "12";
size_t size = sizeof dst;
```

Then with your "Example 1", `dst` becomes `0x31 0x32 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00`

With your "Example 2", `dst` becomes `0x31 0x32 0x00 0x64 0x65 0x66 0x67 0x00`

If you only want to copy the string, then the difference doesn't matter.

It's hard to say which one is better. But in the case of a very big `size` and a very short `src`, setting all the trailing null characters with the "Example 1" approach might make the program a bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

> Do these approaches provide the exact same result, or would there be any differences in `dst` contents between one example and the other?

No, not exactly: both code fragments can perform a string copy operation with truncation if the source string is longer than the destination array, including the null terminator and the resulting string in the destination array will be properly null terminated.

Note however these remarks:

- `strncpy` will also pad the destination array with null bytes up to the full `size` bytes.  This is usually unnecessary and wasteful.
- the first code fragment sets `dst[size - 1]` twice. You could instead write:

  ```
    strncpy(dst, src, size - 1);
    dst[size - 1] = '\0';
  ```
- the semantics of `strncpy` are poorly understood by most C programmers, making it confusing and error prone.  It is recommended to avoid using this function even in cases where it solves the problem.
- the second code fragment, using `strncat` is less wasteful for large destination arrays: it will only modify the necessary bytes, but it is still not optimal.
- both approaches will fail and have undefined behavior is `size` is `0`.

> Which one is preferable:

The second, but an even better solution is to use a custom function that can handle all cases correctly, does not perform redundant copies, tests or padding and returns useful value for the caller to detect truncation.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
size_t safe_strcpy(char *dest, size_t dest_size, const char *src) {
    size_t i = 0;
    if (dest_size) {
        for (; i < dest_size - 1; i++) {
            if ((dest[i] = src[i]) == '\0')
                return i;
        }
        dest[i++] = '\0';  // perform truncation
    ]
    return i;  // return dest_size
}
```

Use it this way:

```
void test_function(const char *str) {
    char buf[200];

    // copy with truncation
    safe_strcpy(buf, sizeof buf, str);

    // copy with truncation and test
    if (safe_strcpy(buf, sizeof buf, str) < sizeof buf) {
        // no truncation
    } else {
        // truncation occurred
    }

    // safe concatenation:
    size_t pos = 0;
    pos += safe_strcpy(buf + pos, sizeof(buf) - pos, str);
    pos += safe_strcpy(buf + pos, sizeof(buf) - pos, str);
    pos += safe_strcpy(buf + pos, sizeof(buf) - pos, str);
    pos += safe_strcpy(buf + pos, sizeof(buf) - pos, str);
    if (pos < sizeof buf) {
        // str was replicated 4 times successfully
    } else {
        // truncation occurred, strlen(buf) is 199
    }
}
```

For completeness, here is the corresponding function for concatenation:

```
size_t safe_strcat(char *dest, size_t dest_size, const char *src) {
    size_t i = 0;
    if (dest_size) {
        while (i < dest_size - 1 && dest[i] != '\0')
            i++;
        for (; i < dest_size - 1; i++) {
            if ((dest[i] = src[i]) == '\0')
                return i;
        }
        dest[i++] = '\0';  // perform truncation
    ]
    return i;  // return dest_size
}
```

Answer (score -2):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncat
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy

Here's a C++ (hahaha) example, illustrating the difference:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/igKe0CtdyuMw1JHL

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// using strncat
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncat

template <std::size_t N>
inline void safestrcpy1(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    constexpr std::size_t count = N-1;
    dest[0] = '\0';
    strncat(dest, src, count); // at most count characters are copied from string src; 
                               // and then a terminating null character '\0' is written if it was not yet encountered
}

template <std::size_t N>
inline void safestrcpy1(char (&dest)[N], const char *src)
{
    safestrcpy1<N>(&dest[0], src);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// using strncpy
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy

template <std::size_t N>
inline void safestrcpy2(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    constexpr std::size_t count = N-1;
    strncpy(dest, src, count); // null termination '\0' is only written if it occurs somewhere within src[0] .. src[count-1]
                               // if it occurs at src[i] and i < count, then dest[i+1], dest[i+2], ... dest[count-1] are also set to '\0'.
    dest[count] = '\0';        // ensure null termination
}

template <std::size_t N>
inline void safestrcpy2(char (&dest)[N], const char *src)
{
    safestrcpy2<N>(&dest[0], src);
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// main
//
int main()
{
    {
        char dest1[4] = "xyz";
        char dest2[4] = "xyz";
        safestrcpy1(dest1, "");
        safestrcpy2(dest2, "");
#define RES1A "\0yz"
#define RES2A "\0\0\0"
        assert(memcmp(dest1, RES1A, sizeof(RES1A)) == 0);
        assert(memcmp(dest2, RES2A, sizeof(RES2A)) == 0);
        std::cout << dest1 << std::endl;
    }
    {
        char dest1[4] = "xyz";
        char dest2[4] = "xyz";
        safestrcpy1(dest1, "1");
        safestrcpy2(dest2, "1");
#define RES1B "1\0z"
#define RES2B "1\0\0"
        assert(memcmp(dest1, RES1B, sizeof(RES1B)) == 0);
        assert(memcmp(dest2, RES2B, sizeof(RES2B)) == 0);
        std::cout << dest1 << std::endl;
    }
    {
        char dest1[4] = "xyz";
        char dest2[4] = "xyz";
        safestrcpy1(dest1, "12");
        safestrcpy2(dest2, "12");
#define RES1C "12\0"
#define RES2C "12\0"
        assert(memcmp(dest1, RES1C, sizeof(RES1C)) == 0);
        assert(memcmp(dest2, RES2C, sizeof(RES2C)) == 0);
        std::cout << dest1 << std::endl;
    }
    {
        char dest1[4] = "xyz";
        char dest2[4] = "xyz";
        safestrcpy1(dest1, "123");
        safestrcpy2(dest2, "123");
#define RES1D "123"
#define RES2D "123"
        assert(memcmp(dest1, RES1D, sizeof(RES1D)) == 0);
        assert(memcmp(dest2, RES2D, sizeof(RES2D)) == 0);
        std::cout << dest1 << std::endl;
    }
    {
        char dest1[4] = "xyz";
        char dest2[4] = "xyz";
        safestrcpy1(dest1, "1234");
        safestrcpy2(dest2, "1234");
#define RES1E "123"
#define RES2E "123"
        assert(memcmp(dest1, RES1E, sizeof(RES1E)) == 0);
        assert(memcmp(dest2, RES2E, sizeof(RES2E)) == 0);
        std::cout << dest1 << std::endl;
    }
}
```